# Iterating through json when new tab is created

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

I want to iterate through a json and send info to html each time a new tab opens. However, the chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener isn't working. Any ideas?

Thank you!

```
    var x;
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function() { 
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)
            myObj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            title = myObj[x].Title;
            date = myObj[x].Date;
            artist = myObj[x].Artist;
            var obj = document.getElementById('main_image');
            obj.style.background = 'url("'+myObj[x].Image+'")';
            document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = title;
            document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date;
            document.getElementById("artist").innerHTML = artist;
            document.getElementById("help").innerHTML = 
   xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        if (x < myObj.length + 1) {
        x = x + 1;
        }
         else {
        x = 0;
       }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL("config.json"), true);
    xmlhttp.send();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with a parameter in the ramada function?

> chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(**tab**) {

And check if the tab.id is properly retriving.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onCreated#Syntax